# Найти совпадающие значения в N массивах Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, ecmascript-6

Допустим есть N массивов чисел, какие то могут быть совсем пустые, какие то длинной порядка 10-20 элементов. Как найти общие элементы для всех этих массивов?

Пример данных:

```
a = [ { id: 1, assetStr: 'hello'}, { id:2, assetStr: 'cat'}, ]; 
b = [ { id: 3, assetStr: 'dog'}, { id: 4, assetStr: 'hello'}, ]; 
c = [ { id: 5, assetStr: 'sun'}, { id: 6, assetStr: 'hello'}, ];
```

Результат на выходе:

```
res = [ { id: 1, assetStr: 'hello'}, ] ;
```

Comment: пустой массив не может иметь совпадающие элементы, покажите пример исходных данных и какой должен быть результат

Comment: @Aleksandr, я понимаю что у пустого нет совпадений, его просто нужно пропустить 
Пример данных: 
a = [
{ id: 1, assetStr: 'hello'},
{ id:2, assetStr: 'cat'},
];

b = [
{ id: 3, assetStr: 'dog'},
{ id: 4, assetStr: 'hello'},
];

c = [
{ id: 5, assetStr: 'sun'},
{ id: 6, assetStr: 'hello'},
]
...
Результат на выходе: 
res = [
{ id: 1, assetStr: 'hello'},
]

Comment: ДА свалить всё, не разбирая, в один массив, подсчитать количество уникальных, и оставить те, у кого количество больше единицы.

Comment: @Akina, кстати да, хороший вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    a = [ { id: 1, assetStr: 'hello'}, { id:2, assetStr: 'cat'}, ];
    b = [ { id: 3, assetStr: 'dog'}, { id: 4, assetStr: 'hello'}, ];
    c = [ { id: 5, assetStr: 'sun'}, { id: 6, assetStr: 'hello'}, ];



    a.forEach(function (a) {
        b.forEach(function (b) {
            c.forEach(function (c) {
                if(a.assetStr == b.assetStr && a.assetStr == c.assetStr){
                    console.log(a);
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Ещё Вариант (в параметр `z` объединяется сколько угодно массивов):

```js
    a = [ { id: 1, assetStr: 'hello'}, { id:2, assetStr: 'cat'}, ];
    b = [ { id: 3, assetStr: 'dog'}, { id: 4, assetStr: 'hello'}, ];
    c = [ { id: 5, assetStr: 'sun'}, { id: 6, assetStr: 'hello'}, ];

    array = [];
    var z = array.concat(a,b,c); //Тут объединяем все массивы
    var arr = [];
    var res = [];
    z.forEach(function (a1) {
        if (arr.indexOf(a1.assetStr) != -1) {
            res['id:'+z[arr.indexOf(a1.assetStr)].id] = a1.assetStr;
        } else {
            arr.push(a1.assetStr);
        }
    });
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но если таких будет 10 то вложенность будет уж слишком большая

Comment: @АнтонШепотько Добавил ещё один вариант снизу, если массивов будет много.

Comment: Второй вариант не будет работать верно, если в любом из массивов ```a, b, c```  будут дублироваться значения